# Explicit initial condition dependent term in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, delay-differential-equations

From my model I get a differential equation in which there is a term which explicitly depends on initial conditions,

the equation is of the form,

$\frac{dx(t)}{t} = a x^2 + b x(t) + f(x_0)$

Where, $x_0$ is an initial condition for the system.

I dont understand if its physible to have such an equation and if yes what does it tell me about the system. Like anything special about the system, its properties etc.

I suspect its something to do with Delay differential equations but i really have no background to understand it firmly.

Any suggestions, any hint will count a lot as i am totally blank on this one.

Thank you very much in advance.

Thanks,

Nitin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once $x_0$ is fixed, you can consider $f(x_0)$ as a constant and solve the equation. If $a,b$ are constants, then the solution with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$ is
$$
\int_{x_0}^x\frac{dz}{a\,z^2+b\,z+f(x_0)}=t-t_0.
$$
In general, you could write the equation as a system:
$$\begin{align}
x'&=F(t,x,y)\\
y'&=0\\
x(t_0)&=x_0\\
y(t_0)&=f(x_0)
\end{align}$$